# Python read datestring from excel file

Tags: python, excel

I have data in excel file with Column A as DateTime String and Column B with data. I want to read the excel file in Python and create dictionary of two elements. The first being a datetime vector and second being data.

The data in excel file looks as:

```
DateTime    Marks
1/1/10 23:00     38.86 
2/1/10 12:00     36.19 
1/1/10 13:00     35.10 
1/1/10 14:00     39.87 
5/1/10 15:00     39.48 
1/1/10 16:00     38.64 
1/1/10 17:00     39.19
```

I wrote the following snippet to start:

```
import xlrd
import os.path
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(os.path.join('C:\Users\JD\Documents\RandomNumber','DateTimeData.xlsx'))
```

But I have no clue what to do next?

Comment: have you tried "google" with "Python read datestring from excel file"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os
import xlrd
import datetime


excel = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'test.xlsx')
book = xlrd.open_workbook(excel, 'r')
data = book.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

for row in range(data.nrows)[1:]:
    excel_date = data.row_values(rowx=row)[0]
    print datetime.datetime(* xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(excel_date, datemode=0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hint anyway. Use a for loop to parse through the file.

```
datetime=[]
data=[]
for line in wb:
      datetime=line.split()[0:2]
      data=line.split().pop()
      strdate=' '.join(datetime)
      if 'DateTime' not in strdate:
        print strdate
        print data
```

This prints out date/time and the data. Hope this helps.